# Why my number of backlinks in Search Console have decreased?

Tags: google-search-console, backlinks, nofollow

We've been noticing for a while that the number of backlinks in Search Console keeps decreasing. We are doing local SEO and we use Yext to push listings on multiple directories (relevant to the industry) with the NAP of our clients.

We have around 60 active listings on different directories for each client which showed as backlinks in Search Console. Now we keep seeing that this number of backlinks is lower and lower.

Do you know if Search Console shows all backlinks in the report or if it includes "nofollow" links in the report? Or a reason why we could see this decrease?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Are these links that Yext is supposedly creating for you or are they links from other sites?

Comment: Yes, basically Yext automatically creates listings with our business information on directories such as Yelp, Yellow Pages, Factual etc and we would see a backlink in Search Console from those directories.

Comment: Sorry. I meant are the links that are disappearing links that Yext created or are they from other  sources?  I.e. organic backlinks, rss feeds, syndicated content, etc. I personally find that GSC is the most accurate list of back links. However, if the links are from newer business directories, some of those may come and go.

Comment: We have mainly seen links that came from Yext disappearing. Now I know that Search Console is supposed to show all backlinks, but it's just weird how this number of links decreased in a short period of time. That's why we came with a hypothesis that maybe it won't show "nofollow" links since these listings only have this thing in common.